# What technology to use to make animation in browser?

Tags: svg, animation, javascript

I want to make an animation of a blob of ink flowing down and then shaping into text. What js libraries can I use. On my research the only way i could find to do this was SVG with GSAP js library. Is there any other  way to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Also a lot of good related questions of you search this site for "web animation"

Comment: One more thing i wanted to do that while i scroll the page. Meaning i want the blob to travel as i scroll

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use an SVG animation (SVGs are great for this because they don't care too much about scaling, its perfect no matter how you scale it). If you can make an animation in an SVG editor such as Illustrator or Inkscape, then import it into your html file via the xml code, hook it up to a scroll library like scrollmagic and you're set!